# Vue Enter/Leave Transition doesn't seem to work well with Opacity

Tags: vue.js, animation, css-transitions

Vue.js v2.2.1

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/loop_/59g7w1pa/8/

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-to, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

".fade-enter-to, .fade-leave" are supposed to set the state after transition, but not working as expected.

**Expected:**
Smooth transition from "opacity 0" to "opacity 0.5"

**Actual:**
Smooth transition from "opacity 0" until "opacity 0.5", then suddenly jump to "opacity 1"

Answer (score 1):

Transition classes are removed and the transition does not have a proper easing, you should add transition property to .square class.

```
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {

  opacity: 0;

}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave {

  opacity: .5;

}

.square {

  margin-top: 2rem;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: opacity .5s linear;

}
```

Comment: Although this could fix the sudden transition, if you apply it to the JSFiddle, the final state is `opacity: 1`. But what I need is the final state being `opacity: 0.5`.

Comment: @ZhihaoZhang The states are just for the transition period, after which whatever CSS classes are applied to the DOM element will render.